# How can i add some pages to a table in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I created a view with two tabs. 
One of the tabs has to be split in multiple pages.

Don't know how to do that with pagination.
Do i need a separate view for each tab or it can still be done in one view?

Can you please help me with an example for the same view?

```
    <div class="w3-bar w3-dark-grey">
        <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink w3-red" onclick="openTab(event,'Statistics')">Statistics</button>
        <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink" onclick="openTab(event, 'History')">History</button>
    </div>

    <div id="History" class="w3-container w3-border city" style="display:none">
        <h2>History</h2>
        @helper ShowHistory(Site.classes.HistoryStruct[] aHistory)
        {
        <br>
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead>
                @if (aHistory == null)
                {
                    <tr></tr>
                }
                else
                {
                    <tr>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Info</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                    </tr>
                }
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tblStatistics">
                @{string sClass = "class='divaproved'";
                    for (int i = 0; i < aHistory.Length; i++)
                    {
                        <tr @Html.Raw(sClass)>
                            <td>@aHistory[i].UserName</td>
                            <td>@aHistory[i].Info</td>
                            <td>@aHistory[i].Date</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
}
        <div class="container">
            @ShowHistory(Site.classes.UserAccessDB.aHistory)
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: It's up to you. You can create a partial view for each tab or put everything in the same view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to paginate your table you can try this js: [DataTables](https://datatables.net/)

Give an ID to the table you need to paginate and add the following code at the end of your page

```
$(document).ready( function () 
 {
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
 } 
);
```